# Display a rich text column in a content query web part

Tags: content-query-web-part, rich-text

Using SP2010, I have a list containing a column with rich text (i.e. contains html).  I would like to display this column using a content query web part - but when I do, it displays the actual html, rather than the formatted text.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to edit the xsl to add a disable-output-escaping attribute.

- [Content Query Web Part example](http://blogs.msdn.com/ben_hickman/archive/2009/05/22/content-query-web-part-example.aspx)

Comment: I've attempted to make this change to the "ItemStyle.xsl" in the "Style Library" - however, I'm not seeing the changes picked up in the CQWP.  Is this not the correct file to modify?

Comment: I haven't done this is SP 2010 yet, but I assume its the same as 2007, and yes that should be the right file. Perhaps edit your question to add the change you made and we can check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I figured out that I was adding the disable-output-escaping attribute to the wrong xsl template. I was using the one labeled "Title and Description" - this corresponds to the "NoImage" template in ItemStyle.xsl

Answer (score 0):

Click on the cell, click on the arrow at right top corner of that cell and choose the appropriate format.